# "A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.\nTry checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition

Tags: android, flutter, dart, async-await, dart-null-safety

```
 handleSignUp() async {
      if (await authProvider.register(
        name: nameController.text,
        username: usernameController.text,
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      )){
```

please help me for this to solve thanktyouuu

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your `register` will return null, you can directly use

```
if(await method()==true){...}
```

I will prefer to create a separate variable for this.

```dart
final bool isRegistered  = await authProvider.register(
        name: nameController.text,
        username: usernameController.text,
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      ) ?? false; // providing false on null case

 if(isRegistered) { ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (await authProvider.register(
      name: nameController.text,
      username: usernameController.text,
      email: emailController.text,
      password: passwordController.text,
    ) !=
    null) {
  print('Registered');
}else{
  print('Something went wrong');
}
```